# Kotlin Check Installed Packages from Array List

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm brand new to Kotlin, I was trying to get a list of installed packages on the device.
I did it correctly because if I pass the value manually it works, but when I put inside a For to get every single package from array to check, it fails to say all the packages are not installed even if a couple of them, passing them manually, works perfectly.
Following the code:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            var checkapk = CheckAPKs()
            //checkapk.isAppInstalled("com.downloadapk", textView, this) mm,
          //  var listOfAvs: Array<String> = Config.avsList.listOfAvs
            var count = 0
            for (apks: String in avsList.listOfAvs) {
                count++
                    textView.text = textView.text.toString() + "\nPKG:" + apks + "\n"
                    checkapk.checkAppInstall(this, textView, apks)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
class CheckAPKs {
fun checkAppInstall(context: Context,textView: TextView, packageName: String?): Boolean {
    return try {
        context.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName,0)
        textView.text = textView.text.toString() +"[V]"+ packageName
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        textView.text = textView.text.toString() +"[X]"+ packageName
        false
    }
}
```

Lastly, the Array with packages list

```
 var listOfAvs: Array<String> = arrayOf(
        "com.thisApk",
        "com.packages2"
        ,"com.packages3")
```

but sadly, as said, I always get "[X]" in the textView instead of "[V]" (means the app is installed) that show when I pass the "com.thisApk")
Any suggestion?
Thanks, anyone :-)

Comment: What Android are you testing this on? You might be getting a permission exception

Comment: Android 11, API 30 emulator.

Comment: Did you add the `<queries>` element to your manifest to deal with [package visibility rules](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring)?

Comment: Hi CommonsWare i didnt, can you explain please?

Comment: About queries, I was thinking that first app it check is the app itself so is not dealing with another app, should say is installed but its not. I'm trying anyway about queries thanks

Comment: <queries> way doesen't work :-( any other suggestions? If I place the same function changing packages names works perfectly but doesen't look a real "way" to do it

Answer (score 0):

Create this function in your activity:

```
fun checkInstalled(uriList: List<String>): Boolean {
   val pm = packageManager
   
   uriList.forEach {
        val app_installed = try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(it, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
            true
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.toString())
            false
        }
       if (app_installed) return true
   }

   return  false
}
```

To use it

```
if (checkInstalled(yourList)) { // Do action }
```